# Using Postgres jsonb type to store array of values vs collection of key/value pairs

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` type column named `selection` in a postgres database. I can store the document in it as

`{ 'selection': ['foo', 'bar'] }`

or just

`['foo', 'bar']`

Both are valid json. Is one style preferred (by typical postgres conventions) or is one more performant than the other at scale?

Comment: I would prefer the first, since it describe the object (in this case: selection).  The second would save some bytes... Even querying will be easier depending on the whole json stored on it...

Comment: If the column is intended to hold selections and is named `selection`, there is no reason to store this redundant info within it. Keep things as simple as possible.